# Panel doesn't auto hide Ubuntu Studio 19.04

Tags: xfce, 19.04, ubuntu-studio, xfce-panel

I've set 'Automatically hide the panel:' to 'Always' AND 'Intelligently'.
'Always' did work for a while but now the panel just won't budge no matter what it's set to! It's really frustrating to have to keep dragging windows down just to see info at the top or to close a window.
Anyone else have this problem? Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: You could issue the command `xfce4-panel -r` in a terminal to restart the panel. Or reinstall the package with `sudo apt install --reinstall xfce4-panel`.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the delay. Restarting the panel does work but It was more of a permanent solution I was looking for, I have done the reinstall so we'll see how it goes. I was also wondering if anyone else has had this problem? It's an upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 to 19.04, maybe that's got something to do with it?